# Trapping events on two fields individually in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to trap events on two custom Fields which I had created by extending the Field class.
The events should only be touch events.

One field uses `graphics.drawRect(10,10,20,20)` and other field uses `graphics.drawRect(50,50,20,20)`.

(I will not use hardcoded values, but am writing them here just for an example).

I should be able to trap the events individually; that means different events on different fields.

My code looks like: 
Main screen Class:

```
     package mypackage;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;


    public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
    {
    CustomFieldManager cfm;

        public MyScreen()
        {
           cfm=new CustomFieldManager(); 
           CustomButtonField cb=new CustomButtonField(Field.FOCUSABLE,20,20,40,40);

           CustomButtonField cb1=new CustomButtonField(Field.FOCUSABLE,70,70,40,40);

           new CustomButtonField(cb,cb1);
           cfm.add(cb); 
           cfm.add(cb1);
           add(cfm);

        }

}


Field class:

package mypackage;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;

public class CustomButtonField extends Field {
    int a,b,c,d;
    CustomButtonField c1,c2;

    public CustomButtonField(long style,int a,int b,int c,int d){
        super(style);
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
        this.c=c;
        this.d=d;
    }
    public CustomButtonField(Object o1,Object o2){
        c1=(CustomButtonField)o1;
        c2=(CustomButtonField)o2;

    }
    public void movefirst(){
        Dialog.alert("god");
    }
protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) {
}

    protected void layout(int width, int height)     {
setExtent(200, 200);

    }


    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {

        graphics.drawRect(a, b, c, d);
    }

    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
        fieldChangeNotify(0);
        return true;

    }
}


    and manager class :

        package mypackage;

    import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;

    public class CustomFieldManager extends Manager {

        CustomButtonField first, second;

        public CustomFieldManager() {
            super(Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL);

        }

        protected void sublayout(int arg0, int arg1) {

            int numberOfFields = getFieldCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFields; i++) {
                // Get the field.
                first = (CustomButtonField) getField(i);

                setPositionChild(first, 0, 0);

                layoutChild(first, 110, 110);
            }

            setExtent(200, 200);
        }


            setPositionChild(first, 50, 50);
            invalidate();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please show the code that defines your two Field subclasses.

Comment: The code above is confusing.  I suspect you are not clear regarding the differences between Fields and Managers and how best to use these.  Rather than comment directly on the code, I would instead suggest you review the UI documentation on the BlackBerry Java micro-site, that you will find here: http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/documentation/intro_to_ui_1969897_11.html

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, you just need to override this method:

```
protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message)
```

in both custom field classes. And implement the functionality you want.

Comment: I have only one class in which there are two rectangles in paint method.I want that i will be able do different tasks by clicking on different rectangles.

Comment: Of course, touchEvent() is problematic on non touch devices.  Personally I would recommend overriding navigationClick() - if you override this you will capture touchEvent clicks and trackpad clicks.

Comment: how to add listeners to these two objects of field class

Answer (score 1):

I think we need some clarification.

A Field in BlackBerry Java is given an 'extent' - basically a rectangle - and it paints into this area.  When displayed on the screen, all 'events' in this Field's extent should be directed to that Field automatically by the framework.  As far as the Field is concerned, the extent always starts at 0,0, and extends as many pixels as the Field has.  In fact it is this extent that defines the size of the Field.

Now within paint, you can paint what you like for the each Field (as long as you stay inside its extent).  So if you have a Field with an extent that was say 100 x 100 pixels, then you paint the left hand side of your Field red and the right hand side blue, by doing something like this:

```java
graphics.setColor(Color.Red);

graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,100);

graphics.setColor(Color.Blue);

graohics.drawRect(50,0,100,100);
```

Now if you did this, you might want separately detectable areas - say the red and the blue areas.  And while this is possible and you can detect it using touchEvent(), you would find it a lot easier to actually display two Fields, one all red and one all blue.  Separate Fields make it a lot easier to use the standard BB methods, and in addition, also make it possible to use the trackpad to scroll round the different Fields.  Remember you can't use touchevent() on non touch phones.

Anyway, with this additional information, can you please clarify your question.  Do you have one Field with different areas?  If you have two different Fields, remember that you are painting within each Field's extent.

Comment: I have one class that extends the Field class and in paint() method i have two drawn two rectangles.first is graphics.drawRect(0,0,30,30) and other is graphics.drawRect(50,50,30,30).My problem is when i click on any of these rectangles same event fires up.I want to do different task on clicking different rectangles.

Comment: @Himanshu, if you want different touch events in the two rectangles, then I think Peter is suggesting that you make these rectangles two **separate** Field objects.  If they are essentially the same (just different colors, and x-y origins), then they could be two **instances** of the same Field subclass.  And, you can still group them together, by putting both Fields into a Manager that contains them both.

Comment: Nate has correctly summarised what I was trying to say.  Further comments with respect to the code in the section above.

Comment: how to add listeners to these two objects of field class